# WPF-Rendering with TranslateTransform and Label

Tags: wpf, rendertransform

i do have the following Code:

```
        private static void AddElements(Canvas canvas)
    {
        double canvasHeight = canvas.Height;
        double canvasWidth = canvas.Width;
        double y0 = canvasHeight / 2;
        double x0 = canvasWidth / 2;

        // Defining the new Coordinate-Point (0,0) to mid auf Canvas
        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform(x0, y0);

        Line line1 = new Line();
        line1.X1 = -350;
        line1.Y1 = 0;
        line1.X2 = 350;
        line1.Y2 = 0;
        line1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line1.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
        line1.RenderTransform = tt;
        canvas.Children.Add(line1);

        Line line2 = new Line();
        line2.X1 = 0;
        line2.Y1 = -350;
        line2.X2 = 0;
        line2.Y2 = 350;
        line2.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line2.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
        line2.RenderTransform = tt;
        canvas.Children.Add(line2);


        Label lblN = new Label();
        lblN.Width = 50;

        lblN.Background = Brushes.Red;
        lblN.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, -350, 0, 0);
        lblN.Content = $"N";
        lblN.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        lblN.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        lblN.RenderTransform = tt;
        lblN.Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(0);
        lblN.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        lblN.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(2.0);
        lblN.RenderTransform = tt;
        canvas.Children.Add(lblN);

        Label lblS = new Label();
        lblS.Width = 50;
        lblS.Background = Brushes.Red;
        lblS.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 350, 0, 0);
        lblS.Content = $"S";
        lblS.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        lblS.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        lblS.RenderTransform = tt;
        lblS.Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(0);
        lblS.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        lblS.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(2.0);
        lblS.RenderTransform = tt;
        canvas.Children.Add(lblS);
    }
```

this method is called on an Menu-Eventhandler and it shows an coordinate system with (0,0) in the mid of the canvas. It should show a label with "N" at the top and a label with "S" at the bottom.

But i shows the attached image [image]

Does anyone know, why lblN looks different than lblS ?

best regards

Volkhard

=============

if i set the height of both Label-Objects to 15

```
lblN.Height=15
:
lblS.Height=15
```

i get the following:
[image: With Setting Height to 15]
i expected the lblN to be more upper on the y-coordinate.

Comment: What happens if you set the `Height` property?

Comment: Helllo @Brannon: 
i edited the post on your question. the result is also not satiesfying: i expected lblN to be more upper on the scale

Comment: Hello @Brannon: also the lblS is at another Y-Coordinate now ...

Answer (score 0):

## What's causing it

Through a bit of testing, I can definitely say that it's the `lblN.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, -350, 0, 0);` that's causing the problem. Apparently, when you give a `Label` a negative margin like that, it will move upwards only as far is it's `Height`, and then it will start expanding instead of just continuing to move. So you end up with a `Label` that's 350 tall. We could try to figure out why that is, but really, that would be missing the point.

Admittedly, I don't have any direct documentation to back up the following statement this, but from years of experience in WPF I feel I can say:

*`Margin` is intended to be used to give space between elements in a dynamic layout, not to give an element an absolute position.*

This behavior of the `Label` seems to strengthen the idea that using `Margin` in this way was not something that was planed for by the designers.

## What you should do instead

`Canvas` has tools for giving an element a set position, yet nowhere do you use `Canvas`'s  `SetLeft`, `SetTop`, `SetRight`, or `SetBottom`. Take a look at the [example on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas#examples). You shouldn't need to use a `TranslateTransform` or set `Margin` at all. Instead, you should calculate where you want the element to be and use one of the above four listed methods to assign that position.

## Extra Tip

Don't use `canvas.Height` and `canvas.Width`, use `canvas.ActualHeight` and `canvas.ActualWidth` instead. The first pair only work if you are explicitly setting the size of the `Canvas` (which it seems you are). But in a senario where the `Canvas` is dynamically sized, the first pair will be `NaN`. The second pair *always* return the actual size that the `Canvas` is.

This doesn't make a difference in your current use case, but it might later on. If you're doing calculations based on the actual size of an element (as opposed to the size you might want it to be), always use `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`.

Comment: Hello @Keith Stein,thanks for your explanations.
i want to use the new coordinate-system with (0,0) at the crossing of the lines because this is like the domain works.as you can see in the sample the Line-objects respect the new coordinate-system and work.

Is there any other way to position a label? or should i use another object than a label?

Comment: @VolkhardVogeler If you want to work logically in the coordinate system where (0,0) is the center, that's fine. You just have to remember that the WPF coordinate system has (0,0) at the top-left. I would suggest creating a pair of functions to convert between center and top-left coordinate space. Do all your calculations in center space, then pass them through the function before applying them to the WPF elements.